# Use custom, composite resource with Azure DSC extension

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-powershell, dsc

I have a VM template that deploys a DSC extension. It's been working fine but my configuration is growing so I've refactored it to use a composite resource and republished it to blob storage with `Publish-AzureRmVMDscConfiguration`.

I verified that the .ps1.zip file in blob storage contains my custom module and that the module is listed under dscmetadata.json. However, when I deploy, the DSC extension fails. The logs under `C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.17.0.0` reveal the reason:

> C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.17.0.0\bin..\DSCWork\AppServerDev.ps1.0\AppserverDev.ps1
>
> PSDesiredStateConfiguration\node : The module 'xCustomResource' could
>   not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module
>   xCustomResource'.
>
> At C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.17.0.0\DSCWork\AppServerDev.ps1.0\AppserverDev.ps1:9 char:3
>
> - node "localhost"
> - ~~~~
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (xCustomResource\xCustomResource:String)
>       [PSDesiredStateConfiguration\node], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoLoadModule,PSDesiredStateConfiguration\node

Here are the relevant bits of my configuration file:

```
configuration AppServerDev
{
    param($environment)
    Import-DscResource -ModuleName 'PSDesiredStateConfiguration'
    Import-DscResource -ModuleName 'SaaSModule'

    node "localhost"
    {
        LocalConfigurationManager
        {
            RebootNodeIfNeeded = $true
            ConfigurationMode = "ApplyAndAutoCorrect"
            ConfigurationModeFrequencyMins = 1440
        }
        xDCTPlatformVM VM {
            OctopusParametersFile = $environment
            ChocolateyPackages = @(
                'googlechrome',
                'notepadplusplus',
                '7zip',
                'microsoftwse',
                'octopusdeploy.tentacle',
                'sqlserver-cmdlineutils'
                )
        }
    }
}
```

Running `Get-Module -ListAvailable` reveals that `DankModule` is found and I can, from powershell, run `Import-Module DankModule` and it works as expected. I assume the confusion is coming from it trying to import `xCustomResource` rather than `DankModule` but my .ps1 file under `C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.17.0.0\DSCWork` says

`Import-Module "DankModule"`

and not

`Import-Module "xCustomType"`

Why is it trying to import `xCustomType` rather than `DankModule`? How do I make it find `DankModule` which is available and contains `xCustomType`?

UPDATE: `Get-Module -ListAvailable` shows `DankModule` is installed but `Get-DSCResource -Module DankModule` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but I think this is a rookie mistake on my part because I have no experience building powershell modules. I was using [this page](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2014/02/25/reusing-existing-configuration-scripts-in-powershell-desired-state-configuration/) as well as [this one](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashleymcglone/2015/02/25/helper-function-to-create-a-powershell-dsc-composite-resource/) to construct my module and I'd gotten a valid module file by using `New-ModuleManifest`, I had the correct file structure mentioned in both of them e.g.

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\

DankModule
    DankModule.psd1
    DankModule.psm1
    DSCResources
        xCustomResource
            xCustomResource.psd1
                RootModule = ‘xCustomResource.schema.psm1'
            xCustomResource.schema.psm1
                Configuration, no Node block
```

but I didn't realize I had some tweaking left. I needed to correct the `RootModule` property in DankModule.psd1 to look like this:

```
RootModule = 'C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\DankModule\DankModule.psm1'
```

And also needed to add to my blank DankModule.psm1 a line referencing my xCustomResource.schema.psm1 equivalent:

```
. .\DSCResources\xCustomResource\xCustomResource.schema.psm1
```

That is the only line in my module-level .psm1 file and everything is now working. I also, at one point, removed all the `\0`s from both my .psd1 files but now I'm not sure if that was strictly necessary.